# two DispatherServlets in one web.xml

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, web.xml

I write spring mvc application.

I Have 2 controllers. I want handles it different instances of dispatcherservlet.

How Can I make it?

controller 1:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        ...
    }

}
```

controller 2:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/restControllerPath")
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping (value = "importantObject", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public  VeryImportantlClass getInformation(){
        ...
    }
}
```

What I need to write in web.xml?

**UPDATE**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>controllerPath/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>restControllerPath/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I see

```
ava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
29.10.2013 21:02:38 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

other trying:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restControllerPath/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

the variant above - 404

**BUT**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

working way

Comment: why do you need 2 dispatcher servlet ?

Comment: second - rest web service and  first - render to jsp

Comment: You say you want 2 dispatcher servlets, but in my answer you say you want one.  Can you update your question to clarify what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the 2 dispatcher servlets to have different configuration contexts, otherwise spring gets confused.  Here's the definition we use for this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>web-spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/web-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api-spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/api-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web-spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>api-spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You should be able to use this type of configuration, just change the contexts and url-patterns to suit your needs.

Note that you will need to change the `@RequestMapping` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/")` for both controllers for this to work.

Comment: I want ONE controller - ONE DispatcherServlet

Answer (score 1):

You will only need one DispatcherServlet.

It can take care of both - the REST Controllers and the JSP rendering.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jspservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jspservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/controllerPath/**url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    /WEB-INF/user-webservice-beans.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>user-webservice</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/restControllerPath/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I want to have different configuration

Comment: different *-servlet.xml files

Comment: why do you want that? what's the benefit?

Comment: yes, you said why you want that. but wants the benefit? it will not make anything faster...

Comment: one project consist rest web service and standart jsp. Use different configuration for it

Comment: shouldn't different projects have different web.xmls?

Comment: ONE web.xml. in one web.xml - two dispatcher servlet mapping

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> restControllerPath/** in servlet mapping

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand why you need two separate dispatcher servlets but, the web.xml configuration should be something like:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/controllerPath/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/restControllerPath/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I see 404 at this way